# I tried several times but still animation is not working, please help me to fix it

Tags: css, animation

**CSS parts**

> Blockquote

I was just making a box and apply animation over it, these are respective lines of code

```
<style>
    .box {
        background-color:red;
        margin-top: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        animation-name: raw;  
        animation-duration: 2ms;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in;         
    }

    @keyframes raw {
        0% {
            background-color: grey;
        }
        50% {
            background-color:lime;
        }
        100% {
            background-color:brown;
        }
    }
</style>
```

**Body**

Here it is a box over which I want to apply animation

```
<body>
    <div class="box">
        BOX
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using ms instead of s. Your animation is working, but it finishes so fast that you just can't see it. Therefore, you should give it a longer duration.